# regular expression for type specifier in php

Tags: php, regex

I need a regular expression which extract **type specifier** ( like  %d,%s) from a string.

```
   <?
     $price = 999.88;
     $str = "string";
     $string = "this is a %f sample %'-20s,<br> this string is mixed with type    specifier like   (number:%d's)";        
    //output 1 :echo sprintf($string,$price,$str,500);
    //output 2 should be $string replaced by [#]
   ?>
```

***output 1***

```
this is a 999.880000 sample --------------string,
this string is mixed with type specifier like (number:500's)
```

i want to replace all these type specifiers with [#].
how do i write an regular expression for that type specifiers.

what i need is

***output 2***

```
this is a [#] sample --------------[#],
this string is mixed with type specifier like (number:[#]'s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pascal beat me to it, but here is my (equally not very well tested regex).

```
'/%(?:(?<swap_position>[0-9]+)\$)?(?<sign>-|\+)?(?<padding>\'.|0|[[:space:]])?(?<alignment>-?)(?<width>[0-9]+)?(?:\.(?<precision>[0-9]+))?(?<type>[%bcdeufFosxX])?/m';
```

I would be concerned that by converting everything to # you lose the information where someone has swapped the order using 2$, 1$ etc.

I wanted to make it so that if you captured a custom padding character prefixed by a quote, that quote wouldn't be captured, but I couldn't work it out.

Comment: yes it is working, is there any exceptions  on your expression?
;) because am not aware of this expression making. where you guys learned these informations please tell me about some good resources.

Comment: You'll find the exceptions when you test it. I've tested it a bit, but not extensively so I make no guarantees..

Comment: thank you very much, any way if there any error i will info you hehe ehe :) (just kidding) . please give me some resources of the regular expression study. :)

Comment: make sure you understand the paragraph in my answer about the order swapping. otherwise this will cause you serious problems.

Comment: one more doubt ---------regu[]lar expre[# # 1]ssio [# # 2]nssadas das dasd as das dasdssd [# # 3]dfs dfsdf sd fsdfds------------ how to extract [# # 1] [# # 2] [# # 3] ...etc what is the expression

Comment: @mittu: ask this as another question

Answer (score 1):

Just is not very-well tested, but what about something like this :

```
$format = "this is a %f sample %'-20s,<br> 
this string is mixed with type specifier like (number:%d's)";

$result = preg_replace("#(%[+-]?(([ 0]?)|('.)))-?(\d*)(\.\d*)?[%bcdeufFosxX]#", '[#]', $format);

var_dump($result);
```

And the result you get is :

```
string 'this is a [#] sample [#],<br> 

this string is mixed with type specifier like (number:[#]'s)' (length=92)
```

Which kinda looks like the string you were asking for.

According to the documentation of [`sprintf`](http://php.net/sprintf), the format has to be :

- % sign
- optional sign specifier : + or -
- optional padding specifier : ' ' or '0'

  - An alternate padding character can be specified by prefixing it with a single quote (')
- optional alignment specifier : nothing or '-'
- optional number, a width specifier
- optional precision specifier : period (`.') followed by an optional decimal digit string
- type specifier : one character amongst the ones allowed

This what I tried to match with that regex ^^

Hope this helps ! Have fun ^^

Comment: You're welcome :-)

(BTW, There's definitly gotta be a way to make this easier to read/understand/maintain ; like splitting the regex in several lines, one for each number on sprintf's documentation page... This can probably be done with a modifier for the regex ; mabye 'x' ; see http://fr3.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php for more informations ;-) )

Comment: Oh, no, it doesn't :-( (didn't know that this was even possible ! thanks for the information, btw :-) ) ; now, I suppose you have to insert something in the pattern somewhere (I can't find a "real" description saying where it should be located ; just before the last character ? )

Comment: @pascal: i think Tom Haigh did that in his code. please check that. :)
where you guys learned these informations ?? ;)

Comment: Where we learnt that ? About regexes, I did a bit of Perl before PHP ; and Perl is really regex-oriented ^^ About sprintf, well, I didn't know everything ^^ And yes, Tom's regex seems to deal with the %$2d thing, AFAI can tell :-)